# How to make a column have a unique value accross other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

Let's say I have a `User` table with a `username` column that has a unique constraint. Now I need to add an `alias` column that must also be unique, but with the added requirement that no two users can have the same `username` and `alias` (`user1.username <> user2.alias`). How would I go about doing this with MySQL?

I know about composite unique indices, but they check against a combination of `username` and `alias` being duplicated, not a combination of one user's `username` being equal to the new user's `alias`.

Comment: I'd probably consider triggers.

Comment: Can `user1.username` be the same as `user1.alias`?

Comment: @mypetlion no, that's not allowed either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relational way would be to make another table `user_names` where each user can have one or many rows in that table.

```
CREATE TABLE user_name (
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  user_name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, user_name),
  UNIQUE KEY (user_name)
);
```

The UNIQUE KEY enforces uniqueness across all users.

The composite PRIMARY KEY makes it efficient to join from the `users` table to the clustered index of `user_names`.

Comment: I've tested this a bit and it does work, but is there no other way to do this that doesn't involve taking `username` and `alias` from the User table?

Comment: Not using a constraint, no. You could use triggers or application code to check for duplicates, but that introduces race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a trigger on that table. The specifics you find here --> https://www.siteground.com/kb/mysql-triggers-use/.

Basically you are going to perform your check before every single insert. Not quite a friend of performance, but that would give you what you need.

```
CREATE TRIGGER aliascheck BEFORE INSERT ON User FOR EACH ROW IF NEW.alias in (select username from User) THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' set message_text='Alias already exists!'; END IF;
```

... Or something like that. I have a TSQL background :)

Comment: This unfortunately creates a lock on every row in the `user` table while it checks. If the transaction doesn't commit very promptly after the insert, you will seriously bottleneck your app.